# Resursive category concat name only leaf mysql query

Tags: mysql, recursive-query

How can I use mysql to merge only the names of the leaf category names?

**Sample table**

| id | name | parentid | active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Main | 0 | E |
| 2 | Test | 1 | E |
| 3 | Test-1 | 2 | E |
| 4 | Test-2 | 3 | E |
| 5 | Test-3 | 4 | E |
| 6 | Test-4 | 4 | H |
| 7 | Test-5 | 4 | E |
| 8 | Test2 | 1 | E |
| 9 | Test2-1 | 8 | E |
| 10 | Test2-2 | 9 | E |
| 11 | Test3 | 8 | E |

**I want output**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | Main > Test > Test-1 > Test-2 > Test-3 |
| 7 | Main > Test > Test-1 > Test-2 > Test-5 |
| 10 | Main > Test2 > Test2-1 > Test2-2 |
| 11 | Main > Test2 > Test3 |

Comment: What have you tried? What problem did you encounter?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried mysql querys but I did not get the exact result I wanted

```html
SELECT t1.id,t1.active,
CONCAT_WS(' > ', t8.name,t7.name,t6.name,t5.name, t4.name, t3.name, t2.name, t1.name) as path
FROM tablename AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN tablename AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.parentid
LEFT JOIN tablename AS t3 ON t3.id = t2.parentid 
LEFT JOIN tablename AS t4 ON t4.id = t3.parentid
LEFT JOIN tablename AS t5 ON t5.id = t4.parentid
LEFT JOIN tablename AS t6 ON t6.id = t5.parentid
LEFT JOIN tablename AS t7 ON t7.id = t6.parentid
LEFT JOIN tablename AS t8 ON t8.id = t7.parentid
WHERE
t1.active = 'H'
```

```html
SELECT c.i AS child_id, c.name AS child_name, c.parentid AS parent_id , p.name AS parent_name, IF( c.parentid, CONCAT( p.name, ' > ', c.name ), c.name ) AS path
        FROM tablename AS c
        LEFT JOIN tablename AS p ON c.parentid = p.id
        WHERE c.active='H'
        ORDER BY child_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT id, parentid current, name path
         FROM test t1
         WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                            FROM test t2
                            WHERE t1.id = t2.parentid)
         UNION ALL
         SELECT cte.id, test.parentid, CONCAT(test.name, '>', cte.path)
         FROM cte
         JOIN test ON test.id = cte.current )
SELECT id, path
FROM cte
WHERE !current
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f57e22bd20d2e9df4e572ec73f1d31b0

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Akina.
In addition to this code, what should we add for those with active = 'E'?

Answer (score 0):

OK, i solved my problem. Thanks

```sql
    WITH RECURSIVE
    cte AS ( SELECT id, parentid current, name path
             FROM test t1
             WHERE t1.active='E' AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                                FROM test t2
                                WHERE t1.id = t2.parentid)
             UNION ALL
             SELECT cte.id, test.parentid, CONCAT(test.name, '>', cte.path)
             FROM cte
             JOIN test ON test.id = cte.current )
    SELECT id, path
    FROM cte
    WHERE !current
```